# Was the "Quetzcoatl, the White God" myth traditional to Mesoamerica?

Tags: history

I heard on an Internet forum that the [Book of Mormon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Mormon)'s claims about [Jesus Christ preaching to a section of natives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatl#Church_of_Jesus_Christ_of_Latter-Day_Saints) in [Mesoamerica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesoamerica) was based on the myths of a white god, [Quetzcoatl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatl).

However, reading online, it seems that the white god myth was not native to the culture and may have, instead, been spread by Cortez afterwards.

**Did the Quetzalcoatl myth (specifically involving a white skinned god who promised to return) exist in Mesoamerican cutlture *before* Cortez?**

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics! We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim that the myth is not a native one is being made.

Comment: http://www.plu.edu/~staffokm/quetzalcoatl-spainish/home.html
 According to wikipedia, this serves as the majority view, but this is the first I've heard of it.

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse. Mesoamerican history is not my strong point. That link says that some (unnamed) scholars suggests Cortés/Cortez wasn't treated as a god, and that this story was spread by (not Cortés, but) the Florentine Codex. That's a fine claim to be examined here, but does that mean we can drop the first paragraph of the question as irrelevant?

Comment: This may be a difficult one since it seems to be a question focused on refuting something that people have pulled out of their posteriors to do some sort of post hoc justification of their myths...  Also not particularly an area that I care to delve into.

Comment: Is this a research level question in history?

Comment: @Sklivvz - yah, throw it onto history.SE. The only way this can be decided is by some obscure documents/books that only a historian would have heard of.

Comment: It is difficult to see what the question is.  Quetzcoatl was one of many central American gods.  He took various forms, in one of which (Topiltzin Quetzalcoatl) he may have departed promising to return.  The Spanish claimed that this had assisted the conquest by Cortés. Quetzcoatl is not mentioned as such in the Book of Mormon, but was put forward later as a possibility by later Mormon apologists.  So which myth, what anachronism, and what false attribution are you asking about?

Comment: As a rule, migrations shouldn't be used to throw poor questions over the fence to be handled by another set of moderators. This question still needs some work clarifying the question before it should be even considered for migration.

Comment: @Oddthinking - I clarified the Q.

Comment: @Henry - I think the claim being questioned is the famous one that there was a pre-existing "white god" myth among Aztecs that helped Cortez in his conquest. There are apparently people who are skeptical of that claim. The Mormon angle seems to be merely an extra layer - Mormons may have claimed (whether they did or not is less relevant to the question) that the claim was somehow related to their religion; and people are extra skeptical of the original claim due to that Mormon connection. Hope this made it slightly clearer.

Comment: This article also sheds some light on the above claim-http://www.examiner.com/article/quetzalcoatl-the-god-the-myth-the-reality-the-man

Comment: This article may also be useful (bulk of article is behind paywall though, but the abstract is not): http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1478-0542.034/abstract